# How to add dropdown list in blogger based on which text content should be displayed for each item in the list?

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, blogger

I am trying to add a drop down list based on which i have to display selected text in a specific post in blogger.

I added dropdown list.
I added java scipt.
But the content is not hiding by default. How can I solve this.
What should i include in addition to correct the code.

Here is my html code of the blogger post

```html
<div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;" trbidi="on">
<script language="javascript">
window.npup = (function (containerId, baseId) {
    // save the container of your special element
    var elementsContainer = document.getElementById(containerId);
    function doSelect(select) {
        // get value of select
        var value = select.value;
        // find element based on the value of the select
        var selected = findElement(value);
        if (!selected) {return;} // didn't find the element, bail
        // do hiding/showing of elements
        hideAll(elementsContainer);
        showElement(selected);
    }
    // retrieve some element based on the value submitted
    function findElement(value) {
        return document.getElementById(baseId+value);
    }
    // hide all element nodes within some parent element
    function hideAll(parent) {
        var children = parent.childNodes, child;
        // loop all the parent's children
        for (var idx=0, len = children.length; idx<len; ++idx) {
            child = children.item(idx);
            // if element node (not comment- or textnode)
            if (child.nodeType===1) {
                // hide it
                child.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    }
    // display a certain element
    function showElement(element) {
        element.style.display = '';
    }
    // hide all on page load (might want some extra logic here)
    hideAll(elementsContainer);

    // export api to use from select element's onchange or so
    return {
        doSelect: doSelect
    };
})('mySpecialElements', 'npup');
</script><br />
<!-- Drop downn section and options -->

<div class="content-selection">
<select id="mySelect" onchange="npup.doSelect(this);">
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <!-- the option values are suffixes for the elements to show -->
      <option value="0">zero</option>
      <option value="1">one</option>
      <option value="2">three</option>
  </select>
</div>
<!-- end of content-selection -->
<!-- container for any elements that are to be in the game -->
<br />
<div id="mySpecialElements">
<!--  these have ids that end with and index  for easy retrieval in "findeElement" function  below-->
    <br />
<div class="hidden" id="npup0">
<h3>
Dive 0</h3>
Content for div 0.<br />
Continue with more content.....</div>
<div class="hidden" id="npup1">
<h3>
Div 1</h3>
This content for div 1<br />
Continue the content here......</div>
<div class="hidden" id="npup2">
<h3>
Div 2</h3>
This is Div 2 content.<br />
Continue the content here.....</div>
</div>
</div>
```

blogger post.

Comment: stackoverflow is not "show me da codez" site. Show your efforts. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Sorry, I have misunderstood that I can get help from scratch. Please neglect my thread.

Comment: I have included the code. Please activate this thread and help me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, for the delayed answer. Was busy with the project tasks.

Here's your working code.

```html
<div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;" trbidi="on">
<script language="javascript">  
  window.onload = function() { 
  
window.npup = (function (containerId, baseId) {
    // save the container of your special element
    var elementsContainer = document.getElementById(containerId);
    doSelect = function(select) {      
        // get value of select
        var value = select.value;
        // find element based on the value of the select
        var selected = findElement(value);
        if (!selected) {return;} // didn't find the element, bail
        // do hiding/showing of elements
      
        hideAll(elementsContainer);
        showElement(selected);
    }
    // retrieve some element based on the value submitted
    function findElement(value) {
        return document.getElementById(baseId+value);
    }
    // hide all element nodes within some parent element
    function hideAll(parent) {      
        var children = parent.childNodes;
        var child;
        // loop all the parent's children
        for (var idx=0, len = children.length; idx<len; ++idx) {
            child = children.item(idx);
          
            // if element node (not comment- or textnode)
            if (child.nodeType===1) {              
                // hide it
                child.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    }
    // display a certain element
    function showElement(element) {
        element.style.display = '';
    }
    // hide all on page load (might want some extra logic here)
    hideAll(elementsContainer);

    // export api to use from select element's onchange or so
    return {
        doSelect: doSelect
    };
})('mySpecialElements', 'npup');
    };
</script><br />
<!-- Drop downn section and options -->

<div class="content-selection">
<select id="mySelect" onchange="npup.doSelect(this);">
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <!-- the option values are suffixes for the elements to show -->
      <option value="0">zero</option>
      <option value="1">one</option>
      <option value="2">three</option>
  </select>
</div>
<!-- end of content-selection -->
<!-- container for any elements that are to be in the game -->
<br />
<div id="mySpecialElements">
<!--  these have ids that end with and index  for easy retrieval in "findeElement" function  below-->
    <br />
<div class="hidden" id="npup0">
<h3>
Dive 0</h3>
Content for div 0.<br />
Continue with more content.....</div>
<div class="hidden" id="npup1">
<h3>
Div 1</h3>
This content for div 1<br />
Continue the content here......</div>
<div class="hidden" id="npup2">
<h3>
Div 2</h3>
This is Div 2 content.<br />
Continue the content here.....</div>
</div>
</div>
```

All I did is just wrap your function inside `window.onload`.